# Can anyone in Naruto universe use all five chakra natures?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto*, I know Sarutobi Hiruzen can use all the five chakra natures.

Has anyone else ever mastered all five?

Comment: Recall Hashirama's ShinsuuSenju which was used by the Zetsu during the Third Great Ninja War,it could use all 5 chakra natures and it was countered by Hiruzen himself.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Nature Transformation](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Nature_Transformation) wiki, there are only 5 shinobi who are known to have mastered all 5 chakra elements by raw training and without the assistance of special abilities or tools.

1. [Hashirama Senju](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hashirama_Senju)
2. [Tobirama Senju](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Tobirama_Senju)
3. [Hiruzen Sarutobi](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hiruzen_Sarutobi)
4. [Orochimaru](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Orochimaru)
5. [Mū](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/M%C5%AB)

Comment: this is incorrect madara could also use all 5 chackra elements

Comment: @xmastertje My answer says *without assistance of special abilities or tools*. The characters mentioned in the other answer had something of the sort, such as Kakazu’s 5 hearts, Obito/Madara being the 10-tailed jinchuraki, and Orochimaru being plain our weird. So by “mastered”, it’s technically corrected - just not complete if including other methods

Comment: But maybe you could also include a list of peope who mastered the 5 chakra elements with the assistance of special abilities or tools to complete the answer more because they also mastered the 5 chakra elements

Answer (score 3):

According to this [website](https://theanimescrolls.com/use-5-nature-transformations/5/), it say that there are 10 people who can use all 5 nature transformations.

Let me breakdown the list:

1. [Naruto Uzumaki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki)
2. [Sasuke Uchiha](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Sasuke_Uchiha)
3. [Madara Uchiha](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha)
4. [Nagato Uzumaki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Nagato)
5. [Hiruzen Sarutobi](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hiruzen_Sarutobi)
6. [Hashirama Senju](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hashirama_Senju)
7. [Tobirama Senju](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Tobirama_Senju)
8. [Obito Uchiha](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Obito_Uchiha)
9. [Orochimaru](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Orochimaru)
10. [Kakashi Hatake](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake)

Other than the website, there are actually quite more people who can **USE** all 5 nature transformations.

1. [Mū](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/M%C5%AB)
2. [Momoshiki Ōtsutsuki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Momoshiki_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)
3. [Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hagoromo_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)
4. [Kaguya Ōtsutsuki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kaguya_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)
5. [Hamura Ōtsutsuki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Hamura_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)
6. [Asura Ōtsutsuki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Asura_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)
7. [Kakuzu](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kakuzu)